# Writeback error in Data Processing Engine

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

I am facing an error in the Writeback Object node of a DPE model. This is the first time I am trying out DPE and encountered this error. The writeback object node is not writing back anything. I tried to debug using workbench and got this info from there:

"sf__Id","sf__Error",Id,_VisibilityDescriptors,test__c,_VisibilityDescriptors

Requested in 0.921 sec
Workbench 56.0.0

The DPE model has two input data nodes of account and opportunity, one join node to join these two objects based on the account ID field, and finally a writeback node. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you checked if you have needed [Permissions to Work with Data Processing Engine](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.concept_data_processing_engine_permission.htm&type=5) `The writeback user specified in a Writeback Object node requires Create access on all the target objects and fields selected in the node. If the Writeback Object node contains related field mappings, the user requires Create access on the related fields also.`

Comment: Yes, I have System Admin access.